# Serialize function is not called

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I am trying to debug save/load feature implemented with Boost serialization, but it doesn't work. I founded that the problem is caused by class tile:

```
class tile : public game_object {
...
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template <class Archive>
void serialization(Archive ar &, const unsigned int version) 
{
    throw new std::exception;    //I expect this will be thrown when serializing, but it isn't
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<game_object>(*this);
    ...
}
```

Saving to archive:

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(...);
tile t = ...;
archive << t;
```

Loading from archive:

```
boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(...);
tile t;
archive >> t;
```

The problem is, that data members from class tile which are not in class game_object are not saved and loaded. Function tile::serialize is never called, but function game_object::serialize is called.

Thanks for help and sorry for my english.

Comment: how do you know it's not thrown? Did you catch `std::exception*`? Because using `new` in `throw` is very strange c++

Comment: No I didn't catch anything but I think it would terminate the program. But the exception is not important. The point is, that code in tile::serialize is not executed. And I know that, because I also had there logging to file, which wasn't executed and breakpoint, which wasn't triggered.

Comment: I know that is the point. I was just checking the facts as your question is pretty low on details. Why don't you create a SSCCE? We might be able to fix it up for you... (then again, browsing existing answers should give you this information)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. The method to serialize should be called "serialize" instead of "serialization".

Comment: Nice spot. I remember doing a similar thing once. It's tricky that the base class serialization kicks in (so no error results). With the SSCCE, I wouldn't have missed it :)